# Bootstrap 3 grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a newbie in html/css/bootstrap and I need help with my project.
I attached illustration of my current grid.
My question is what would be method to make div's closer to each other. How to make div from left column closer to div from middle column and div from right column closer to div from middle column?
Div in middle column should stay centered.
Left div is set to float: right and right div is set to float: left. And all padding is set to 0.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code or create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com)?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/124942#

Comment: So, I want to first div with image to be closer to second div. Also third to be closer to second. And second to stay centered. If that makes any sense :)

Comment: I've been looking through this and the only way I can see it being done is to break bootstrap. The col-md-1 has a specific width. You'll have to reduce that width and then increase the width of the surrounding col-md-5s to make it stay properly balanced.